# How to pass parameter in Macros?

Tags: excel, vba

I am calling below function as

```
Dim SheetName As String
Dim FirstName As String, LastName As String
FirstName = "Patricia "
LastName = "Katts"
SheetName = GetFullName(FirstName, LastName)


Private Function GetFullName$(First As String, Last As String)
Dim FName As String
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = _
WorksheetFunction.Text(FName)
FName = First & Last    
GetFullName = FName
End Function
```

but I got error as Compile Error : Argument Not Optional. What's wrong in this code. I do not understand.

Comment: try replacing `worksheetfunction.text(FName)` with simply `FName`. You're assigning a string, you dont need to call a function to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a parameter here: `WorksheetFunction.Text(Value, Format_Text)`

But you don't need the worksheet function, you can use `ActiveSheet.Name = fName`  With the caveat that you change the operation order.  It would evaluate to `vbNullString` in the current order.

This should work fine:

```
Sheets.Add
FName = First & Last    
ActiveSheet.Name = FName
GetFullName = FName
```

It is possible you may expect `.Text`to do something it is not meant to do.  You might want to go back to your worksheet and type "=text(" in the formula bar and read the tool tip.

I'm not sure what's going on with the top part of your example.  You are receiving the parameter in the function just fine but you aren't passing it from anywhere.  Maybe I am just confused by your formatting.

These must be inside a sub, function, or property and cannot be in the open like you have them.

```
Dim SheetName As String
Dim FirstName As String, LastName As String
FirstName = "Patricia "
LastName = "Katts"
SheetName = GetFullName(FirstName, LastName)
```

Something like this

```
Sub PassingToFunction()

Dim SheetName As String
Dim FirstName As String, LastName As String
FirstName = "Patricia "
LastName = "Katts"
SheetName = GetFullName(FirstName, LastName)

End Sub
```

I literally copied and pasted your example.  Made the edits I suggested and it works.

```
Sub WorksJustFine()
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim FirstName As String, LastName As String
    FirstName = "Patricia "
    LastName = "Katts"
    SheetName = GetFullName(FirstName, LastName)
End Sub

Private Function GetFullName$(First As String, Last As String)
    Dim FName As String
    Sheets.Add
    FName = First & Last
    ActiveSheet.Name = FName
    GetFullName = FName
End Function
```

You're doing something that isn't being explained.

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: And when get that issue, what line is highlighted ?

Comment: function name Private Function GetFullName$(First As String, Last As String)

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it!